# How to plot a fat dot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to plot a red dot with x and y and it should be really 'fat', three times thicker in diameter than a regular matplot graph. How can I do that?

`plt.plot(x, y, something else)`

What should I write instead of `something else`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
plt.plot(x, y, markersize=(put integer number whatever you want))
```